# How do I get specific data from my localstorage so I can show them in a modal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example, let's say I have:

student[ id : 1, Name: Jake]

student[ id : 2, Name: John]

so far what I have is

```
 const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = "#";
  link.addEventListener("click", function(){openModalCallback()}, false);
  link.textContent = student.id; 

  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  let cell = document.createElement("td");
  
  row.appendChild(cell);
  cell.append(link);
```

this just opens the modal that contains the data. How do I specifically access the 2nd student when I click on his ID so only his data will be shown in the modal?

Comment: Just use the id as the key for the localstorage property and the student object as its value. Don't forget that local storage only takes strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways. I like to add data-id='x' to the anchor element. Then when the anchor is clicked get that data id and use it in the lookup.

so:

```
<a id="personSelect" href="#" data-id="1">John Smith</a>
```

and you have an object:

```
var student = {
   1:Jake,
   2:John
}
```

You can get the data-id with:

```
const person = document.getElementById('personSelect');
const id = person.dataset.id;
```

Then you can access the person

```
student[id]
```